# Is the left-handed neutrino, after seesaw, still the left-handed neutrino?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos

Reading this question and its answer

[Seesaw type-1 and integrating out heavy fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/130121/seesaw-type-1-and-integrating-out-heavy-fields)

The diagonalization of the see-saw is described as going from "*interaction basis" right (and left) handed neutrinos* to  *"mass basis" right (and left) handed neutrinos*.

Now, can chirality refer to a particular basis? Is it not a general property connected with parity? I would think that our "left handed neutrino" after seesaw is not a left neutrino anymore, but that it has a small mixing with the "right handed neutrino".

EDIT: and if it is so... is it always so, or there is some see-saw mechanism that preserves chirality?

Comment: Yes, you're right, of course. It can be easily observed for case of two neutrinos.

Comment: But when right neutrino mass values is much larger than "Dirac mass" matrix values than you can neglect the right neutrinos.

Comment: @AndrewMcAddams Ik, so just in case someone wants to answer, I will expand the questio ;-)